# Type of static subclass method types in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, jss

In Typescript I'm trying to get part of the type of a static getter class.

Here's a concrete example, where I'm trying to figure out how to get `CSSTypes`:

```
class View {
  static get css (): Record<string, any> {
    return {}
  }

  get jss (): CSSTypes {
    /* return JSS-created CSS class names.
       Equivalent in type (but not in practice, since we defer to the JSS library) to:

       return Object.assign({},
         ...Object.keys(this.constructor.css).map(k => {[k]: `${k}-css-class-name`})
       )
     */
  }
}
```

I want `CSSTypes` to be a map of string keys of `static get css` to another string.

```
class WebComponent extends View {
   static get css () {
      return {
        list: {
           display: 'grid'
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Here's what we get from the console:

```
>>> wc = new WebComponent()

// wc.jss should have one key, `list`
>>> wc.jss.list // === something like 'WebComponent__list-0-0-1'
```

If I were to take a stab at what we'd need, it'd look something like (which obviously doesn't work but kind of illustrates the idea):

```
class View {
   ...
   get jss: Record<keyof typeof this.constructor.css, string> {...}
}
```

#### Context

For this example I'm using JSS with Knockout/TKO and we have hundreds of web-components, and since the documentation of what CSS variables exist from the `jss` getter is present (as the keys that are returned from `static get css`) we're hoping there's some magic Typescript that can figure it out without having to duplicate anything.

We use `this.jss` many thousands of times, so adding a type to that would be challenging, so we are hoping that we can add a type to `get jss`.  Ideally we'd only modify the super class  getter for `jss`.  The `jss` getter is never modified i.e. exists only in the super class, but `static get css` is specific to every component.

To save memory and increase performance we (generally) have only one JSS style object per class type, hence `static css`.

This seems outside the scope of what Typescript ordinarily documents, and well outside my competence with it, but I'm hoping it's achievable since it theoretically seems possible.

Comment: What do you expect `keyof typeof this.constructor.css` would resolve to? (if it worked as you would like it to work). Note: you could try replacing `this.constructor.css` with `View.css`, it could be what you want.

Comment: Eh, I think without [stronger typing for `this.constructor` (microsoft/TypeScript#3841)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841) and/or [polymorphic `this` for static members](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) it might be difficult to get this done without redundant annotations.

Comment: The workaround for strongly-typed `this.constructor` from #3841 gives [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBqCWBTA7tA3gWAFDV9A2gETAD2AdhAC4BOArsJSdYQLoBc0lAngA6IkAzOEmQBuaAHoJ0ADwBaOdDKJEAE04loYMmRKUwlRNHhloiAG6JqXaBFoAjUJAjY8t-ZXjBoAc0SVoYCgACgBKDhJ7ACtEBnRoan9aalMyWhAQAEJxCQAqeABbHhBc6QBfVzw-AKiQ8OgAJVimVRkAa0QuQU4AC3gIIlIKGnpGZhZBqFYAGndqEx8APnjEymTU9Kyc-KKS8uwKrCcoaAB1RHsAYRIi8kQyAMQAD0MyVRgEFHRK3EHyKjoDCYrA43D43XOVxuPDuD0k0nkimUag0Wh0egMRkofRcODwVAMXl8-kCdW+eLcuFW63iIH6lA4aGgqn6xTAXA4AHIfPNVJzoGUBT8hVhDkMqNBkN4ALxKL6Q663ZQPMIAOlqEBy0jQdKoHABCzKQA); does it suffice?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks.  The #3841 workaround is a cool but not very feasible in our code base.  I think waiting for the static types to get fixed in Typescript may be the correct answer here.